# How to export PostgreSQL database structure while ignoring objects created by PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, export

I want to export the database structure from a PostgreSQL database. I want to include all tables, functions, etc., created by me but exclude everything created by database extensions like PostGIS. What is the easiest way how to do that?

The problem is that there are hundreds of functions and procedures in the same (`public`) schema as my own functions.

Comment: Would _not_ creating your objects in the `public` schema be an option?

Comment: Well, they are already there :)

Comment: Did you try it?  This is automatically the way it works.  Extensions are dumped by their "CREATE EXTENSION..." statements, not by listing their individual objects.  (There are some exceptions to this, but for postgis that exception is a single config table, not hundreds of things)

Comment: @jjanes Of course. You are right that there are only a few extension tables. BUT there are about a thousand functions and procedures...

Comment: But those functions should not get dumped.  What version of postgresql and postgis are you using?

Comment: I want to dump functions and procedures as well because there are many of my own. The problem is that they are in the same scheme (public) as the PostGIS functions... PostgreSQL 12.12,  PostGIS 3.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *pg_dump* utility to export the structure of your PostgreSQL database.

To exclude objects created by database extensions like PostGIS, you can use the *--exclude-extension* option followed by the name of the extension. For example, to exclude all objects created by the PostGIS extension, you can use the following command:

```
pg_dump --exclude-extension=postgis -U <username> -s <databasename> > <outputfile>
```

This command will create a SQL script that includes the structure of all tables, functions, etc., created by you, but excludes everything created by the PostGIS extension. The *-s* option specifies that only the database schema should be exported, without the data.

You can customize the command further by specifying additional options such as the *--schema* option to include only specific schemas, or the *--table* option to include only specific tables. You can also pipe the output of *pg_dump* to a compression utility such as *gzip* to create a compressed backup file.

Comment: There does not seem to be any such parameter of [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html). Where do you have this information from?

Comment: This option doesn't exists